Sorry, the action failed unexpectedly! when applying security roles to user and teams in Microsoft Dynamics
In dynamics / power platform I recently made a copy of our production environment (configuration only). However, now whenever I attempt to add roles to users or teams I get the error: Sorry, the action failed unexpectedly! The log indicates a bad request (400). I've attempted using Power Automate and the Dataverse WEB api to achieve the same, but with the same result.
Other functionality seems to be working as expected, I just can't assign any roles. I'd very much appreciate any hints at what I could look at to fix this issue.
